# Spring Boot groovy compilation error: Unexpected token @ @ line 45

Tags: groovy, annotations, spring-boot

I'm trying to convert a Java controller in my Spring Boot project to Groovy, and getting the strangest error when trying to compile and run

```
unexpected token: @ @ line 45, column 5
@RequestMapping(value = {"/v1/foo", "/foo"}, method = GET)
^
```

This is baffling to me. Annotations are annotations in Java or Groovy, right? what am I missing? Here's an abstraction of my code

```
// src/main/groovy/my/package/FooController.groovy, formerly .java

/// ... proper imports

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class FooController {

    // ... @autowire services

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/v1/foo", "/foo"}, method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity get(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
      // do work return ResponseEntity
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/v1/foo", "/foo"}, method = PUT)
    public ResponseEntity put(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @ResponseBody @Valid final MyFoo myFoo) {
      // do work return ResponseEntity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I'm just dumb and missed a key differentiator between Java and Groovy

The problem is the `value` I'm passing to `@RequestMapping`

In Java, `{"/v1/foo", "foo"}` is an array literal

In Groovy, `{"/v1/foo", "foo"}` is a closure

The error message obviously wasn't helpful, but to fix this I simply needed to change the annotation in Groovy to pass in an array literal as I intended, not a closure

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/v1/foo", "/foo"], method = GET)
```