# Autowiring class in controller, throwing unexpected token '@' in syntax @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, autowired

While Trying to autowire a service class to my restcontroller in springboot, it is throwing build error unexpected token @, at @Autowired notation

This is my controller class.

```
@RestController
class RestAPIController{

@Autowired
private getTextBooks service

@RequestMapping(value = "/textbooks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Interface for autowiring

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
public interface Books{
    public String getText(String name)

}
```

Class implementing Interface

```
@Componet 
Class getTextBooks implements Books{
@Override
def getText(String name){
return "Text Book Name is" + name
}
}
```

Unable to Autowire in Controller

Comment: Next time, remember that line error given by build errors are not always the line given. Look around to find the bug.

Comment: Also it's convention to have class names start with a capital letter

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417338/spring-boot-groovy-compilation-error-unexpected-token-line-45?rq=1) out

Comment: Thank you tim_yates, i started the class name with capital letter and all worked fine. All this time I was looking for errors specific to @Autowire and Bean Injection :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your class in capital letter like :

```
@Componet 
Class GetTextBooks implements Books{
 @Override
 def getText(String name){
  return "Text Book Name is" + name
 }
}
```

It's java convention to name class by starting with Capital case letters.